# how to create a jpeg picture with a triangle of 3 specific point and specific color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Now I'm trying to create a jpeg picture with a triangle of 3 specific point and specific color .

like this:
a jpeg picture (256 * 256)
I got three points and a specific color
draw the triangle filled with the color to the jpeg

I'm using python2 with pillow(forked by PIL)

Comment: See [ImageDraw.Draw.polygon](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.polygon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw polygon using [`ImageDraw.Draw.polygon`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagedraw.htm#tag-ImageDraw.Draw.polygon):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

points = (20,20), (20, 100), (100,20)

im = Image.new('RGB', (255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(points) # outline='red', fill='blue'
im.save('triangle.jpg')
```

Comment: oh! Thank you! I think I need to watch the api for pillow carefully and try my best to learn Eng better ..

Comment: another question: the pic newed by your method does not look clear. Am I missing any parameter(s)?  Can it be more clear ?

Comment: @PikeSZfish, try using png instead of jpg. Sorry for veeeery late response.